# Math annotations in stargazer summary tables

Tags: r, stargazer

I am using stargazer to make latex tables containing math expressions. Everything works well in regression tables:

```
data("cars")
library("stargazer")

cars
m <- lm(speed ~ dist - 1, cars)

# a data frame containing variable labels
vars <- data.frame(raw = c("speed", "dist"), labels = c("$Speed^{in}_t$", "$Cars \\times Space^{in}$" ), stringsAsFactors = F)

        raw                    labels
1 speed            $Speed^{in}_t$
2  dist $Cars \\times Space^{in}$

out <- stargazer(m, covariate.labels = vars$labels[2])
out
 [1] ""                                                                                                           
 [2] "% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu"
 [3] "% Date and time: Do, Feb 27, 2020 - 17:10:24"                                                               
 [4] "\\begin{table}[!htbp] \\centering "                                                                         
 [5] "  \\caption{} "                                                                                             
 [6] "  \\label{} "                                                                                               
 [7] "\\begin{tabular}{@{\\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} "                                                                 
 [8] "\\\\[-1.8ex]\\hline "                                                                                       
 [9] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[10] " & \\multicolumn{1}{c}{\\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\\\ "                                                
[11] "\\cline{2-2} "                                                                                              
[12] "\\\\[-1.8ex] & speed \\\\ "                                                                                 
[13] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[14] " $Cars \\times Space^{in}$ & 0.308$^{***}$ \\\\ "                                                           
[15] "  & (0.015) \\\\ "                                                                                          
[16] "  & \\\\ "                                                                                                  
[17] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[18] "Observations & 50 \\\\ "                                                                                    
[19] "R$^{2}$ & 0.896 \\\\ "                                                                                      
[20] "Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.894 \\\\ "                                                                             
[21] "Residual Std. Error & 5.291 (df = 49) \\\\ "                                                                
[22] "F Statistic & 423.468$^{***}$ (df = 1; 49) \\\\ "                                                           
[23] "\\hline "                                                                                                   
[24] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[25] "\\textit{Note:}  & \\multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\\\ "             
[26] "\\end{tabular} "                                                                                            
[27] "\\end{table} "
cat(out, sep = '\n', file = "test.tex")
```

However, when I try to make a summary table containing variable names that have math expressions::

```
r <- do.call(cbind, lapply(cars, mean)) %>% t() %>% data.frame
rownames(r) <- vars$labels

out <- stargazer(r, summary = F)
out

 [1] ""                                                                                                           
 [2] "% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu"
 [3] "% Date and time: Do, Feb 27, 2020 - 17:19:40"                                                               
 [4] "\\begin{table}[!htbp] \\centering "                                                                         
 [5] "  \\caption{} "                                                                                             
 [6] "  \\label{} "                                                                                               
 [7] "\\begin{tabular}{@{\\extracolsep{5pt}} cc} "                                                                
 [8] "\\\\[-1.8ex]\\hline "                                                                                       
 [9] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[10] " & . \\\\ "                                                                                                 
[11] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[12] "\\$Speed$\\hat{\\mkern6mu}$\\{in\\}\\_t\\$ & $15.400$ \\\\ "                                                
[13] "\\$Cars \\textbackslash times Space$\\hat{\\mkern6mu}$\\{in\\}\\$ & $42.980$ \\\\ "                         
[14] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[15] "\\end{tabular} "                                                                                            
[16] "\\end{table} "
```

In particular, the output changes from `$Cars \\times Space^{in}$` to `\\$Cars \\textbackslash times Space$\\hat{\\mkern6mu}$\\{in\\}\\$`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Not optimal, but as a temporary fix:

```
r <- do.call(cbind, lapply(cars, mean)) %>% t() %>% data.frame

out <- stargazer(r, summary = F )

vars$raw <- paste0("^", vars$raw, " &")]
vars$raw <- gsub("_", "\\\\_", vars$raw, fixed = T)]
vars$labels <- paste0(vars$labels, " &")

for(i in 1:nrow(vars)){
  out <- gsub(vars$raw[i], vars$labels[i], out)
}
out

out <- gsub("times", "\\\\times", out)
out

 [1] ""                                                                                                           
 [2] "% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu"
 [3] "% Date and time: Do, Feb 27, 2020 - 19:09:05"                                                               
 [4] "\\begin{table}[!htbp] \\centering "                                                                         
 [5] "  \\caption{} "                                                                                             
 [6] "  \\label{} "                                                                                               
 [7] "\\begin{tabular}{@{\\extracolsep{5pt}} cc} "                                                                
 [8] "\\\\[-1.8ex]\\hline "                                                                                       
 [9] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[10] " & . \\\\ "                                                                                                 
[11] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[12] "$Speed^{in}_t$ & & $15.400$ \\\\ "                                                                          
[13] "$Cars \\times Space^{in}$ & & $42.980$ \\\\ "                                                               
[14] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                      
[15] "\\end{tabular} "                                                                                            
[16] "\\end{table} "
```